# I Want to Increase the count in csv file when Person Face gets Detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, opencv

Whenever a Recognized Face gets detected, the system times in the attendance for that person and I want a count to increase whenever Attendance is taken but if new person comes in I want the count to reset from 1 and whenever he comes 2nd or 3rd time it keeps incrementing !

The function for taking attendance (In Time):

```py
def TrackImages():
    check_haarcascadefile()
    assure_path_exists("Attendance/")
    assure_path_exists("StudentDetails/")
    for k in tv.get_children():
        tv.delete(k)
    msg = ''
    i = 0
    j = 0
    count = 1
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()  # cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
    exists3 = os.path.isfile("TrainingImageLabel\Trainner.yml")
    if exists3:
        recognizer.read("TrainingImageLabel\Trainner.yml")
    else:
        mess._show(title='Data Missing', message='Please click on Save Profile to reset data!!')
        return
    harcascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath);

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    col_names = ['Id', '', 'Name', '', 'Date', '', 'Count', '', 'In Time', '', 'Out Time']
    exists1 = os.path.isfile("StudentDetails\StudentDetails.csv")
    if exists1:
        df = pd.read_csv("StudentDetails\StudentDetails.csv")
    else:
        mess._show(title='Details Missing', message='Students details are missing, please check!')
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        window.destroy()
    while True:
        ret, im = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 5)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (225, 0, 0), 2)
            serial, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])
            if (conf < 50):
                ts = time.time()
                date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
                timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                aa = df.loc[df['SERIAL NO.'] == serial]['NAME'].values
                ID = df.loc[df['SERIAL NO.'] == serial]['ID'].values
                ID = str(ID)
                ID = ID[1:-1]
                bb = str(aa)
                bb = bb[2:-2]
                attendance = [str(ID), '', bb, '', str(date), '', count, '',str(timeStamp), '', '']
                

            else:
                Id = 'Unknown'
                bb = str(Id)
            cv2.putText(im, str(bb), (x, y + h), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Taking Attendance', im)
        
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
            break

    psw()

    
    ts = time.time()
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    exists = os.path.isfile("Attendance\AttendanceIn_" + date + ".csv")
    if exists:
        with open("Attendance\AttendanceIn_" + date + ".csv", 'a+') as csvFile1:
             writer = csv.writer(csvFile1)
             writer.writerow(attendance)
        csvFile1.close()
        
    else:
        with open("Attendance\AttendanceIn_" + date + ".csv", 'a+') as csvFile1:
            writer = csv.writer(csvFile1)
            writer.writerow(col_names)
            writer.writerow(attendance)
        csvFile1.close()
    with open("Attendance\AttendanceIn_" + date + ".csv", 'r') as csvFile1:
        reader1 = csv.reader(csvFile1)
        for lines in reader1:
            i = i + 1
            if (i > 1):
                if (i % 2 != 0):
                    iidd = str(lines[0]) + '   '
                    tv.insert('', 0, text=iidd, values=(str(lines[2]), str(lines[4]), str(lines[6])))
    csvFile1.close()
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output (in csv file):
[image: Actual Output]

Expected Output:
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: code's syntax (indentation) is broken. please fix. [edit] your post.

Comment: why use pandas but then *not* use its csv reading/writing facilities?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.